# Can't append select2 elements inside <p>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I am still curious about why I can't add select2 elements (from bootstrap) inside `<p>`.

I have 2 files

order.php:

```php
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-icons/entypo/css/entypo.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/neon-core.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/neon-theme.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/neon-forms.css">

        <!-- Imported styles on this page -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/js/select2/select2-bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/js/select2/select2.css">

        <!-- Bottom scripts (common) -->
        <script src="assets/js/gsap/main-gsap.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/joinable.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/resizeable.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/neon-api.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

        <!-- Imported scripts on this page -->
        <script src="assets/js/select2/select2.min.js"></script>
        <!-- JavaScripts initializations and stuff -->
        <script src="assets/js/neon-custom.js"></script>

    <?php 
    if($_POST['type_order']=="Personal"){
    ?>
   <span>
    <select name="personal_order" class="select2">
    <option value="person1">Person 1</option>
    <option value="person2">Person 2</option>
    <option value="person3">Person 3</option>
    </select>
  </span>
    <?php }else{?>
  <span>
    <select name="company_order" class="select2">
    <option value="company1">Company 1</option>
    <option value="company2">Company 2</option>
    <option value="company3">Company 3</option>
    </select>
  </span>
    <?php }?>
```

main_form.php :

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $(document).on( 'change', '.typeorder', function()
    {

        var type_order=$("#typeorder").val();
        
         $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "order.php",
            data: {type_order:type_order},
            cache: false,
            success: function(html)
            {
                $(".order").find('span').remove();

                $(".order").find('p').append(html);

            } 
        });

    });
```

```html
   <select name="x_type_order" id="typeorder" class="typeorder select2">
   <option>Choose order</option>
   <option value="Personal">Personal</option>
   <option value="Company">Company</option>
   </select>                   
<div class="order">
<p>
</p>  
</div>
```

The appended  select2 element inside p does not show up.
but if I check using inspect element it's added properly, why does this happen?

Comment: hmm where is `.order` in your html?

Comment: _if i check using inspect element it's added properly_ what you find inside the `p`??!!

Comment: @mrahmat sorry have an edit at the <p> the .order is class from div

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki ,i find <p> inside .order class and append it with .select2 elements

Comment: So what you mean by _not showed up_ when you say that you find it ? is it hidden ?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki yes it is hidden, is the select2 elements not showed up because it's loaded by ajax ?

Comment: No should shown if you don't have no classe/style that hide it. but as shown in your example the `order.php` will return not just the select2 but also all the includes and that may cause a problem. (try to add a screenshot that shows the select hidden in the interface and inspector shown it.

Comment: i have tried not to include all those jquery, but still not showing up

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki
its the screenshot : 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_e6zk7T5Lt-elMxel9PRnJrZDg/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

instead of finding p elem, why not try to get them directly?
this is may one of many way to do that $(".elem p").append(string);

```
    var type_order=$("#typeorder").val();

    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "order.php",
        data: {type_order:type_order},
        cache: false,
        success: function(html)
        {
            $(".order span").remove();

            $(".order p").append(html);

        } 
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dw09h9oj/1/

Comment: have you try to add the select2  inside of it ?

Comment: pls check the jsfiddle link,
hm, maybe i didn't get your real question,

so, if your code was succesfully added to document, but not showing up maybe there is some css issue, have you check for that?

Comment: yes i have done that without select2 , the problem is, it can't showed up with select2 elements, i meant this select2 :
https://select2.github.io/

and maybe you need the screenshot :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_e6zk7T5Lt-elMxel9PRnJrZDg/view?usp=sharing